# OCaml: the variant type unit has no constructor ::

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to implement sets through lists.. This is the code with the implementation (I omitted the interface):

```
module MySet : Set = 
  struct
    type 'a set = 'a list
    let empty : 'a set = []
    let add (x: 'a) (s: 'a set) : 'a set =
      if not(List.mem x s) then x::s 
    let remove (x: 'a) (s: 'a set) : 'a set =
      let rec foo s res =
    match s with
    | [] -> List.rev res
    | y::ys when y = x -> foo ys res
    | y::ys -> foo ys (y::res)
      in foo s []
    let list_to_set (l: 'a list) : 'a set = 
      let rec foo l res =
    match l with
    | [] -> List.rev res
    | x::xs when member x xs -> foo xs res
    | x::xs -> foo xs (x::res)
      in foo l []
    let member (x: 'a) (s: 'set) : bool = 
      List.mem x s
    let elements (s: 'a set) : 'a list =
      let rec foo s res = 
    match s with
    | [] -> List.rev res
    | x::xs -> foo xs (x::res)
      in foo s []
  end;;
```

This is the error I get

```
Characters 162-164:
        if not(List.mem x s) then x::s 
                                   ^^
Error: The variant type unit has no constructor ::
```

I can't understand the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a very confusing message that we got since 4.01 that stems from the fact that you have no else branch and that () is a valid constructor for `unit`.

Since you have no else branch the whole `if` must type to `unit` and thus the `then` branch aswell and it tries to unify the expression in the `then` branch with a value of type `unit` and detects that `::` is not a constructor for values of type `unit`.

What you wanted to write is:

```
if not (List.mem x s) then x :: s else s
```

Without an `else` branch your `add` function needs to type to `'a -> 'a set -> unit`

The strange error message is being bug tracked in OCaml's issue tracker, see [PR 6173](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6173).